# Problemas con el build.gradle para implementar firebase

Tags: android, firebase

Buenas estoy intentando implementar firebase a una aplicacion de android pero siguiendo la guia de firebase mi proyecto me esta dando un error que no se como solucionar.

El error que me indica es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

mi build gradle a nivel de proyecto es el siguiente

```
 plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.4.1' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.4.1' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.8.0' apply false
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        // Make sure that you have the following two repositories
        google()  // Google's Maven repository

        mavenCentral()  // Maven Central repository
    }
    dependencies {

        // Add the dependency for the Google services Gradle plugin
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'

    }
}




allprojects {
    repositories {
        // Make sure that you have the following two repositories
        google()  // Google's Maven repository

        mavenCentral()  // Maven Central repository

    }
}
```

y mi build gradle a nivel de aplicacion es el sigueinte:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'

}

android {
    namespace 'com.example.aplicacionfirebase'
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.aplicacionfirebase"
        minSdk 24
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:31.2.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx'
}
```

y por ultimo esta es la guia que me ofrece la pagina de firebase y el codigo que me esta dando problemas:

[[image: Guia firebase2]

Tenemos que realizar un proyecto en el que hacer el un login y el usuario pueda registrarse mediante su cuenta de google o correo electronico. Sin embargo sin esta configuracion no puedo realizarlo, unicamente puedo hacer las vistas. Muchas gracias de antemano‍

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema se produce dentro del archivo `build.gradle` ubicado en la raiz de tu proyecto, el mensaje de error indica el problema:

> buildscript {} blocks must appear before any plugins {} blocks

(**Los bloques `buildscript{}` deben aparecer antes que los bloques `plugins{}` en tus archivos `build.gradle`** )

Debes declarar el bloque `plugins{}` después del bloque `buildscript{}`, realiza el siguiente cambio:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        // Make sure that you have the following two repositories
        google()  // Google's Maven repository

        mavenCentral()  // Maven Central repository
    }
    dependencies {

        // Add the dependency for the Google services Gradle plugin
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'

    }
}


 plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.4.1' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.4.1' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.8.0' apply false
}


allprojects {
    repositories {
        // Make sure that you have the following two repositories
        google()  // Google's Maven repository

        mavenCentral()  // Maven Central repository

    }
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias me ha servido de mucha ayuda ‍